# Find The NSTimer is Invalidate Or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I need to find the NSTimer Invalidate Or not in if Condition....!

Because,NSTimer once Invalidate after another Invalidate is Crash the application...!

Any one help me with us....!

Thanks..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store a timer in a member variable you should retain it. Because probably you created it using `timerWithTimerInterval:`

Anyhow. If your reference is valid you can check it using **[myTimer isValid];**

If you *don't* retain your timer, you should at least assign nil after invalidating it.

```
[myTimer invalidate];
myTimer = nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if([timerInstance isValid]){
//then invalidate
}else{
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the timer in a variable and then check using

```
[timer isValid]
```